# OpenCV: HSV inRange returns binary image squashed and repeated

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, object-recognition

I'm having a bit of trouble with an image that I'm converting for colour recognition.

The function looks like this:

```
void PaintHSVWindow(cv::Mat img){
cv::Mat HSV, threshold; 
cvtColor(img, HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
inRange(HSV, cv::Scalar(HMin, SMin, VMin), cv::Scalar(HMax, SMax, VMax), threshold);
Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));
Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(8, 8));
erode(threshold, threshold, erodeElement);
dilate(threshold, threshold, dilateElement);
cv::resize(threshold, threshold, cv::Size(360, 286));
MyForm::setHSVWindow(threshold);
```

}

And the output looks as follows:

[image: Input on the left, output on the right, filtering to find the yellow ball]

On the left is the input. On the right is *supposed* to be the same image, converted to HSV, filtered between the given thresholds to find the yellow ball, eroded and dilated to remove the smaller contours, and displayed in half the size of the original image. Instead, it takes the expected image and squashes 3 of them in the same space.

Any guesses as to why this would happen?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

OK, since it appears that running findContours on the image on the right-hand size still gives me the proper output, i.e. the contours from the distorted, 3-times-copied right-side image can be pasted into the right position on the left-side input image, I've decided to just take the distorted image and crop it for display purposes. It will only ever be used to find the contours of a given HSV range in an image, and if it serves that purpose, I'm happy.

Comment: Presumably; this has something to do with chanel conversions. In most cases, these things happen when 3 channels are expected, but one is provided (or the other way around).
Try printing in between results.

Comment: indeed, the image should have been converted to black-and-white first, perhaps

Comment: The only step in between is the HSV conversion, and that looks as I would expect it. It's the inRange function returning the frame split into 3 like that.

Comment: Also @Ashalynd converting it to black and white removes all the colour information that I need to, y'know, identify colours with.

Comment: Could you post your values for the HSV ranges. That way we don't have to guess when trying to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Aurelius, here's the specs for the HSV range.  
`H[26, 33], S[133, 255], V[75, 191]` 
Although I'm not sure if the range information will help. It comes back as 3 images regardless of the range.

Comment: The odd thing is, applying the findContour function to the image on the right gives me the expected results; i.e. if I draw the contours over the main image on the left, it lines up... very strange...

Comment: MyForm::setHSVWindow(threshold);, //<-- what does it do ? i guess, you just got a problem blitting b/w images correctly

Comment: @berak Perhaps. That's not a bad assumption. I'll check into my routine used to post those images. But I've just managed to crop the image and display the black and white image, so it works fine as is.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?

Answer (score -1):

As @Nallath comments, this is apparently a channel issue. According to the documentation, the output of [`inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#inrange) should be a 1-channel `CV_8U` image which is the logical `AND` of all channel inclusives.

Your result means that somewhere along the way `threshold` is being treated like a 3-channel plane-order image.

What version of OpenCV are you using?

I suggest that you show `threshold` between every step to find the place where this conversion happens. This might be a bug that should be [reported](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki#Reporting-bugs).